# How to define the first revision of the branch (SVN)

Tags: svn

I have a branch which was copied from trunk.
Branch was created at revision 10000 for example.
Current trunk revision is 12345 for example.

How I can define the first branch revision (1000) using svn command line?

My variant is:

1) Get the xml log into log file:
 svn log -v --xml > log.xml

2) Analyse this file and find something about
 copyfrom-path="%TRUNKPATH%" rev-no="10000" action="A">%BRANCHPATH% 
and get revision number.

But it is a very difficult because it is need to analyse whole file.

Does exists another, more simply way to get a first branch revision?

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

There is a `--stop-on-copy` parameter that will limit the log of the current WC to stop at the first copy. This should give you a log of *only* the branch.

You could then just get the last entry.

```
svn log --stop-on-copy --xml
```

From the [svnbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html):

> --stop-on-copy
>
> Causes a Subversion subcommand that traverses the history of a versioned resource to stop harvesting that historical information when a copy—that is, a location in history where that resource was copied from another location in the repository—is encountered.

Comment: Not --xml here, but -q... | grep \| | tail -1